# How to refresh every 1 minute between specified time?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel sheet the below code automatically refresh the sheet every 1 minute.

What I am looking is how to refresh the sheet automatically within given time?

For example: I want the sheet to refresh automatically every 1 minute only between 9:20 am to 9:25 am. The sheet must not refresh on other time i.e., before 9:20 am and after 9:25 am.

```
Sub UpdateCell()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:0"), "UpdateCell"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call TimeInterval
End Sub
Sub TimeInterval()
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:20:00"), "UpdateCell"
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:21:00"), "UpdateCell"
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:22:00"), "UpdateCell"
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:23:00"), "UpdateCell"
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:24:00"), "UpdateCell"
    Appication.OnTime TimeValue("9:25:00"), "UpdateCell"
End Sub
Sub UpdateCell()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

You will need to allow programmatic access to the VB project

Navigate to Trust Center > Macro Settings and select Trust access to the VBA project object module.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The time is 1:40 PM now and if the run the macros the sheet is refreshing. I don't want the sheet to refresh after 9:25 or before 9:20

Comment: @vvkprabhu That cannot be because of that code. Also what does *"if the run the macros"* mean you don't need to run any macros the macro `Workbook_Open` will run automatically when the workbook opens.